# Why are my python plots not styled like modern ggplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, ggplot2, survival-analysis

I've been following along with [this](http://lifelines.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Intro%20to%20lifelines.html#estimating-the-survival-function-using-kaplan-meier) tutorial, using my own data set. I can get the plots to show, but they don't look as nice as the ones in that website.

For comparison, here's one I'm getting:[image]

and here is one in their example:[image]

I had to add `plt.show()` to get my plot to show, so is this what's causing it? It seems like theirs is a ggplot and mine is off of matplotlib, so I'm guessing that's the root of the cause. However, I just can't get my plots to show without adding that line, so I'm not sure what to do. This will be for a report, so I'd really like to get the nicer looking plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/), import it:

```
import seaborn
```

and do your plot again.

Also, turn on the inline mode for matplotlib in the notebook:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Alternatively use:

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

for zoomable plots.

Plot before:

[image]

Plot after:

[image]

these steps.